# Tomcat Denying access to resource file in exploded war directory

Tags: java, tomcat7, war

We have a WAR application deployed on Tomcat 7.0.65. This application uses a library that has a bunch of polygon.txt files in it's resource directory. Whenever the library is invoked it throws a file permission exception on the jar file in the exploded war directory.

here is the error:

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/**/WEB-INF/lib/table-service-1.37.jar" "read")
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResourceAsStream(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1659) ~[catalina-7.0.65.jar:7.0.65]
    at com.**.PropertyGeometryDAO.initialize(PropertyGeometryDAO.java:47) ~[table-service-1.37.jar:?]
```

Thrown at this line in the code:

```
try (InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName))
```

Here is the catalina.policy file defining the permissions:

```
permission java.io.FilePermission "/usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/*", "read";
```

We also have separate WAR's deployed on the same Tomcat using the same library that are working just fine.

Comment: How about specifiying read,wite acess both?
 https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-manager-howto.html#Tomcat_Custom_Permissions

Answer (score 1):

The exception is for

```
"/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/**/WEB-INF/lib/table-service-1.37.jar"
```

but your permission is for

```
permission java.io.FilePermission "/usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/*", "read";
```

Comment: I should have included, there is a link from /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps -> /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps

Comment: You may need the readLink FilePermission then https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilePermission.html